# Mathematics for algorithms

Tags: algorithms

What are the best books for a programmer to improve his mathematical skills ? I am actually good at programming,but when it comes to mathematical problems,i fail sometimes !! any tips to improve my skills ?

Comment: *[B]ut when it comes to mathematical problems, i fail sometimes* — so do we mathematicians!

Comment: @ bRian M.scott Thanks for the reply sir !!:) Any suggestions regarding books ?

Comment: I would guess Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming* would be the standard reference. Definitely not for the weak of heart and reading it would already require strong mathematical skills, though.

Comment: Have you ever worked through an undergraduate text in discrete mathematics?

Comment: @ Brian M scott ya..i am actually doing my second year computer science and engineering in INDIA :) I love maths to the core,but we people are supposed to score marks in our college more than"we understand",so everything teachers do in a score-oriented approach!! I am really worried about my mathematical skills @@ I need some inspiring books ? So that i can get started !!

Comment: Scheinerman, [*Mathematics: A Discrete Introduction*](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Discrete-Introduction-Edward-Scheinerman/dp/0534398987/ref=pd_cp_b_0), is a pretty good introduction to discrete mathematics **and** to understanding and writing proofs.

Comment: Depending on what kind of book you're looking for, I would perhaps recommend "Fermat's last theorem" by Simon Singh. It is more of a popular science book with some history than it is a text book, but I really enjoyed it.

Comment: _Concrete Mathematics_ by Knuth, Graham, and Patashnik (? not 100% sure about the 3d guy's name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More often the problem lies simply in your Mathematical skills. I would first go to improve your pure mathematics knowledge and then after that trying to applying them to programming.

Regarding books there are plenty of them, like:

[http://www.amazon.com/Nonlinear-Programming-Classics-Applied-Mathematics/dp/0898713412](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898713412)

Comment: Thanks for the reply !! But can you suggest me any inspiring books to read,so that i can start thinking mathematically ?